# Может ли kdeconnect-cli одновременно запускать множество параллельных запросов?

Tags: php, sms

Хочу создать свою систему верификации пользователя при регистрации. Тут возникает вопрос: сможет ли kdeconnect-cli одновременно высылать 100 смс разным пользователям, которые в один момент запросят одноразовый код?